# How to design micro-services in the below scenario :-

Tags: java, database-design, architecture, nosql, microservices

I have to design an application using micro services architecture using Java-Spring boot which has the below use cases :-

1. The user should be able create account in the portal.
2. User should be able to view / browse the online educational courses and add the courses to shopping cart.
3. The user should be able to buy the courses by doing an online payment.
4. The user should be able to view / play the courses which he/she has purchased.

Queries :-

1. How many micro services should be created and what will be those?
2. How do we relate the data so that we can map which user has purchased which courses? ( In RDBMS we usually we use a foreign key constraint ) . How is data usually related in such scenarios using micro services architecture?
3. Which database will be suitable for such architecture and how many data stores will be there?

Request you all to be as specific as possible in the solution.

Comment: Always keep API and UI micro-services separate and  communication should be done through REST API.....

Answer (score 0):

**Answer1:**
As per your Requirement you can create  following micro services

1. Registration
2. Login
3. Education Courses
4. Shopping Cart
5. User Courses

Answer2:
**In User Courses table you can store User info as well as course info(both Id's)**

Answer 3:
**You can use mysql or mongodb or combination of this depends on your requirement.
If you will create 5 schema or will take 5 different database it would be good.**

Comment: If the database of users and courses are different, then how will we relate both the data ? User and courses?

Comment: How will you relate 3 and 5 data? as databases are different?

Comment: @Lalit Whenever user login you can take user data from user table with id and when user will make payment for any course you can take that data from shopping cart table and both data you can store in user_courses table.On the basis of user id you can easily find which courses should be accessible to user using user_courses table.